# Guessing game optimal strategy and related question.

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I was making a simple guessing game program for a class. You input a number, the program tells you if your number is higher or lower than the number. I found what I believe to be the optimal strategy, where you start in the center of the numbers (e.g. 1 to 100, start with 50). There is also a step size, which halves every time you guess in the game, and starts at 1/4 of the amount of numbers. If the number is lower, you subtract the step size rounded up, and if it's higher, you add the step size. With numbers between 1 and 100, it takes 7 guesses or less. This question is not about the strategy, rather the numbers that take the most step. I believe know why they are all even, because the number starts as odd, so an odd number will likely take fewer steps. 50 and 100 make sense to be missing as well, because some steps may remain when reaching 100, and the solution starts at 50. What I don't know is why are the numbers 12, 38, 62, and 88 missing from the list?
Here is the list I made, by the way.

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98]
```

The guessing game code is

```
from random import randint

number = randint(0, 100)

print("Guessing game. I have a number between 1 and 100. Guess a number, and I will tell you if it's higher or lower than my number")

while True:
    guess = input("Please enter a number: ")

    try:
        guess = int(guess)
    except:
        print("Please enter a number")
    
    if guess < 0:
        print("Your number must be higher than 0")
    elif guess > 100:
        print("Your number must be lower than 100")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Your guess is lower than my number.")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is higher than my number.")
    elif guess == number:
        print("You win!")
        break
```

The code I made to test the solution is the following.

```
import math

number = 50
step = 25

steps = 0
temp_steps = 0

longest_numbers = []

for i in range(1, 100):
    while number != i:
        temp_steps += 1
        if i < number:
            number -= step
        elif i > number:
            number += step
        step = math.ceil(step / 2)
    number = 50
    step = 25
    if temp_steps > steps:
        steps = temp_steps
        longest_numbers = []
    if temp_steps == steps:
        longest_numbers.append(i)
    temp_steps = 0

print(steps)
print(longest_numbers)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: "Why is 12,38,62,88 missing from the list?"  For the same reason that 50 is missing from the list.  Because these are among the early numbers guessed.

Comment: I don't know how that went completely over my head.